# c++ Passing a const struct that contains a pointer - how to move through the values?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, struct, constants

```
    typedef struct {
        unsigned int width;
        unsigned int height;
        PBYTE pixels;
    } PBYTEImage;

    void someFunction(const PBYTEImage& inputImage)
    {
        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < inputImage.width*inputImage.height; x++) 
        {
            unsigned char y = *(inputImage.pixels);
->          inputImage.pixels += 1;
        }
    }

Error: expression must be a modifiable value
```

Am I modifying the contents of PBYTE ? I thought `inputImage.pixels += 1;` would only advance the pointer `PBYTE` to the next value... Is that correct ?

What want:

- the contents of the struct should not be modified by the function
- the function should be able to read the struct, and advance the pointer PBYTE as it reads its data

I don't think I can make the items inside struct as const since the caller has to assign their values.

What is the best way to do it ?

```
    void someFunction(const PBYTEImage* inputImage)
```

had the same effect.. it seems the const applies to the struct which does not allow me to modify its pointer, including the value the pointer is pointing at...

Do I have to drop the const ? Is there no way to show that the function does not modify the data ?

Edit: the `PBYTE` is

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;   
typedef BYTE near *PBYTE;
```

defined in `minwindef.h` or `windef.h`

Sorry for not mentioning it

Comment: why not just `struct PBYTEImage{...}:`?

Comment: what is `PBYTE`? `char*`? Also you might want to change your for-loop....

Comment: Use a different pointer? `PBYTE other = inputImage.pixels;` ... `++other;`. Currently your loop has no effect, you \read `y` and do nothing with it.

Comment: `PBYTE` is an pointer to one `BYTE` (unsigned char). @Ceris, why would he need to say `struct PBYTEImage{ ... }`? The OP would like to use `PBYTEImage` as the variable type rather than saying `struct PBYTEImage` as the variable type. There is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: The function does modify the data, which is the pointer in the struct. There is a difference between a const pointer and a pointer to const data.

Comment: I forgot the loop increment :-o .... If I use a different pointer will I have to delete it at the end or will the fact that it points to an existing pointer take care of it ?

Comment: @samgak I realize that, which is the reason for my question... how can I make the function not modify the actual data just navigate through it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I have to drop the const ? Is there no way to show that the function does not modify the data ?

Actually, your function does change the parameters data since you're incrementing inputImage.pixels.
So you probably want to store inputImage.pixels and iterate that instead.

```
void someFunction(const PBYTEImage& inputImage)
{
    PBYTE pPixels = inputImage.pixels;
    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < inputImage.width*inputImage*height;) 
    {
        unsigned char y = *pPixels;
        pPixels += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Will I have to free pPixels at the end of the function ?

Comment: you cannot use pPixels to free the memory after incrementing because it needs to point to the exact same location. so either decrement pPixels or simply free inputImage.pixels.

Comment: I wish I had seen this comment sooner, I have been struggling to figure out a crash in the caller of a function because the original pointer to the pixels had been moved... Since the inputImage.pixels is sent from the caller, and I am using a pointer to it, if I do at the end pPixels -= inputImage.width * inputImage.height; do I still have to free pPixels ?

Comment: `PBYTE pPixels = inputImage.pixels;` doesn't allocate any memory. They both are variables (pointers). You can use both to free the memory as long as you keep the original offset of it on deletion. So if you want to free the memory using pPixels after iterating you **must** call `pPixels -= inputImage.width * inputImage.height;` in order to prevent a crash.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a typo in the exit condition of your for loop: you have written

```
inputImage*height
```

but it should be

```
inputImage.height
```

Apart from this, you haven't told us what PBYTE is, but from this line

```
unsigned char y = *(inputImage.pixels);
```

I suppose that somewhere you have

```
typedef unsigned char* PBYTE;
```

So PBYTE is a pointer. The expression

```
inputImage.pixels += 1;
```

does indeed try to increment the pointer, pixels. Since pixels is a member of your struct, and your struct is passed as a const, you are getting the error. So yes, if you want to keep your struct as it is and increase the pointer, you must drop the const in your function definition. Changing from passing inputImage as reference to passing it as pointer won't help either.

> Do I have to drop the const ? Is there no way to show that the
>   function does not modify the data ?

Maybe you are expecting to be safe from a const-ness point of view because you are just moving a pointer and not touching the data that it is pointing to: that's right, but in this case the pointer itself is your data, and you are trying to change it. So your function **does** modify the data.

Comment: Added Microsoft reference to PBYTE and thanks for pointing out my typo. Yes this is my understanding too, exactly as you say, and I am trying to find the best way to pass my struct in code while making it clear that the function will not modify the data.